# My OPENGL GLFW window is not updating color over time

Tags: c++, opengl, time, graphics, glfw

I'm following along in the openGL superbible  the seventh edition.

In the project I'm looking at is supposed to make a background color that changes over time in the window created. The  source files for all the projects and the setup I used are available at https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb7code. I'm running it on release in Visual Studio 2017.

Below is the output window's output:

```
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Danie\OneDrive\Documents\sb7code-master\sb7code-master\bin\singlepoint.exe'. Module was built without symbols.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\win32u.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32full.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp_win.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvhm.inf_amd64_ebea877f10dfbbc7\nvinit.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ig8icd32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\windows.storage.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\fltLib.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igdusc32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wtsapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvhm.inf_amd64_ebea877f10dfbbc7\nvinit.dll'
The thread 0x169c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxgi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d11.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ResourcePolicyClient.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ResourcePolicyClient.dll'
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvhm.inf_amd64_ebea877f10dfbbc7\nvinit.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igd10iumd32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igd10iumd32.dll'
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igd10iumd32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ncrypt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcrypt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcrypt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcrypt.dll'
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntasn1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvhm.inf_amd64_ebea877f10dfbbc7\nvinit.dll'
The thread 0x3168 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\TextInputFramework.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreUIComponents.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreMessaging.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinTypes.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinTypes.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinTypes.dll'
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinTypes.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinTypes.dll'
```

I know that  the symbols are not too necessary to print out in the output because they are primarily for debugging if there is an error within a DLL. However I feel like the origin of the problem is this line:
'singlepoint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvhm.inf_amd64_ebea877f10dfbbc7\nvinit.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
I may be completely wrong but it's the only thing I can see out of place at the moment.

The source cpp file for this project:

```
 /*
      Copyright © 2012-2015 Graham Sellers

      Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a
     copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"),
      to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation
      the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense,
      and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the
      Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

      The above copyright notice and this permission notice (including the next
      paragraph) shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the
      Software.

      THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
      IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
      FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.  IN NO EVENT SHALL
     THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
      LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
      FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
      DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
     */
 #include <sb7.h>

class simpleclear_app : public sb7::application
{
    void init()
    {
        static const char title[] = "OpenGL SuperBible - Simple Clear";

        sb7::application::init();

        memcpy(info.title, title, sizeof(title));
    }

    virtual void render(double currentTime)
    {
        static const GLfloat color[] = { (float)sin(currentTime*20)*2.5f+.5f,
                                         (float)cos(currentTime*20)*2.5f+.5f,
                                         0.0f, 
                                         1.0f};
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, color);
    }
};

DECLARE_MAIN(simpleclear_app)
```

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].

Comment: I've made an edit to simplify it to only a changing color over time. I know that I should work because it's written in the  Super Bible book. Hopefully this is enough for everyone. If not let me know what I need to do to fix it and I will.

Comment: "I know it should work because it's written in the Bible". Sir, you made my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
virtual void render(double currentTime)
{
    static const GLfloat color[] = { (float)sin(currentTime*20)*2.5f+.5f,
                                     (float)cos(currentTime*20)*2.5f+.5f,
                                     0.0f, 
                                     1.0f};
    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, color);
}
```

You've marked `color` to be `static`. This means it'll only receive a value the first time this function is called, and will never be updated again (and because it's marked `const`, it cannot be altered after initialization without depending on undefined behavior). Remove the `static` keyword, and this function should behave the way you expect it to.

Also, the "Cannot find or open the PDB file" error is irrelevant and has no bearing on your problem. The only consequence of it is that it's more difficult to step through certain functions in your debugger.

Comment: Thanks so much! It seems so obvious now. I'll have to keep that in mind for the future! Thanks again!